# SVN repository structure advise

Tags: .net, svn

I have some experience in using subversion, but I require some advise in structuring my repository correctly in the first place.

I have multiple small unrelated projects, but i also have a couple of global projects that many of these smaller projects are dependant on. The global projects contains reusable libraries etc which is common to the other projects.

Do i just have one repository, but have a project root (trunk) for each project (i.e. one for each project including the global ones)?

I don't want to put all of the projects in the same root, as they are mostly unrelated except the global project.

At the moment all the small project's solutions specifically include global project, which means they can update the source code, but this means if something is committed into global all projects will be affected. Is it better to seperate this more and only include the global dll in the project? that way i can make sure only that version of global is used for that project?

Thanks for the advise!

Comment: I have the same requirement. I used the `external` subversion property to put either the binaries or the source code of my common projects under each consuming projects.

Comment: externals with PEG-revisions and **repository per project**! See at this [Assembla project](https://www.assembla.com/code/subversion-troubleshoot-b/subversion/nodes) for *not a best, but usable* sample (check trunk and tags). Not best - because HEAD-linking was used, PEG may be better for you

Answer (score 1):

There are two fairly practical options:

```
big_project
  trunk
  branches
  tags
little_project_1
  trunk
  branches
  tags
little_project_2
  trunk
  branches
  tags
```

Or

```
trunk
  big_project
  little_project_1
  little_project_2
branches
  branch_x
    big_project
    little_project_1
    little_project_2
  branch_y
```

Etc.

If the projects have little to do with each other besides sharing some common utility libraries or some such, I'd go with option 1, as it keeps them more neatly separated. If they're closely tied together, option 2 has the advantage that you can check them all out with one check-out.

I don't think it matters a whole lot either way. Note that option 2 does not force you to update all the projects together: you can commit just one project under trunk.

If the only thing they share is some utility libraries, I'd consider breaking these libraries out into their own project, so you don't have to suck in the entire big_project just to get three functions.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using external directives in the small project to bring in the libraries from the big project.

The SVN External directive has some features that work best when the external (big project) is in the same repository so I would not recommend using separate repositories. Use separate top level folders for each project. Like Jay's option 1.

When you use the external directive link to a specific revision in the big project so that changes to the big projects do not affect the small projects. When a small project is ready to take advantage of a change in the big project they can change their external directive to link to the new revision.

Comment: "has some features that work best when the external (big project) is in the same repository" - really?! Mixed revision and dirty history aren't "features that work best". Amout of requests is also equal (+1 for each externals) for both types of references. **RTFM!**

Comment: SVN allows importing individual files into your project from other paths in the same repository. However you can only import whole folders from other repositories.  File externals cannot refer to files from other repositories.